# warn_unused_result attribute and returning class object

Tags: c++, gcc, warnings

Please consider the following code:

```
class cls
{
};

__attribute__((warn_unused_result))
cls fn1()
{
    return cls();
}

__attribute__ ((warn_unused_result))
int fn2()
{
    return 1;
}


int main()
{
    auto x = fn1();
    (void)x;

    auto y = fn2();
    (void)y;

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile this with `-Wall -Wextra` with gcc 5.4.0, I get **a** warning:

```
warning: ignoring return value of ‘cls fn1()’, 
declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
```

Can somebody tell me what's wrong?
Why this warning appears for `fn1` despite the `x` variable, and why it does NOT appear for the `fn2`?

---

**Update 1**: With a little help, I tried this with g++ 4.8.3 - the same result. Even more - g++ 3.3.6 produces two warnings - for `fn1` and `fn2`.

What "fixes" the warning is...... guess what - adding a **data** member or a **virtual** member function in the class (a non-virtual function does not help). Sounds like a compiler bug to me.

**Update 2**: Actually adding a member or a virtual function disables the warning completely, so just calling `fn1();` does NOT produce the warning anymore.

Comment: This looks like the same bug as: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=38172

Comment: What if for `fn1` you instantiate then return... does it give the same warning? `cls a; return a;`

Comment: @DustinGoodson - yes, it does.